# TCL/TK script issue with string match inside if-statement

Tags: bash, tcl

I have a script in bash that calls a TCL script for each element on my network which performs some actions based on the type of the element. This is part of the code that checks whether or not the hostname contains a specific pattern(e.g. *CGN01) and then gives the appropriate command to that machine.

```
if {[string match "{*CGN01}" $hostname] || $hostname == "AthMet1BG01"} {
    expect {
    "*#" {send "admin show inventory\r"; send "exit\r"; exp_continue}
    eof
    }
}
```

With the code i quoted above i get no error BUT when the hostname is "PhiMSC1CGN01" then the code inside the if is not executed which means that the expression is not correct.

I have tried everything (use of "()" or "{}" or"[]" inside the if) but when i dont put "" on the pattern i get an error like:

```
invalid bareword "string"
in expression "(string match {*DR0* *1TS0* *...";
should be "$string" or "{string}" or "string(...)" or ...
(parsing expression "(string match {*DR0* *...")
invoked from within
"if {$hostname == "AthMar1BG03" || [string match *CGN01 $hostname]...
```

or this:

```
expected boolean value but got "[string match -nocase "*CGN01" $hostname]==0"
while executing
"if {$hostname == "AthMar1BG03" || {[string match -nocase "*CGN01" $hostname]==0}...
```

when i tried to use ==0 or ==1 on the expression.
My TCL-Version is 8.3 and i cant update it because the machine has no internet connecticity :(

Please help me i am trying to fix this for over a month...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match a string that is either exactly `AthMet1BG01` or any string that ends with `CGN01`, you should use

```
if {[string match *CGN01 $hostname] || $hostname == "AthMet1BG01"} {
```

(For Tcl 8.5 or later, use `eq` instead of `==`.)

**Some comments on your attempts:**

(The notes about the expression language used by `if` go for `expr` and `while` as well. It is fully described in the documentation for `expr`.)

To invoke a command inside the condition and substitute its result, it needs to be enclosed in brackets (`[` `]`). Parentheses (`(` `)`) can be used to set the priority of subexpressions within the condition, but don't indicate a command substitution.

Normally, inside the condition strings need to be enclosed in double quotes or braces (`{` `}`). This is because the expression language that is used to express the condition needs to distinguish between e.g. numbers and strings, which Tcl in general doesn't. Inside a command substitution within a condition, you *don't* need to use quotes or braces, as long as there are no characters in the string that you need to quote.

The string `{abc}` contains the characters `abc`. The string `"{abc}"` contains the characters `{abc}`, because the double quotes make the braces normal characters (the reverse also holds). `[string match "{*bar}" $str]` matches the string `{foobar}` (with the braces as part of the text), but not `foobar`.

If you put braces around a command substitution, `{[incr foo]}`, it becomes just the string `[incr foo]`, i.e. the command isn't invoked and no substitution is made. If you use `{[incr foo]==1}` you get the string `[incr foo]==1`. The correct way to write this within an expression is `[incr foo]==1`, with optional whitespace around the `==`.

All this is kind of hard to grok, but when you have it is really easy to use. Tcl is stubborn as a mule about interpreting strings, but carries heavy loads if you treat her right.

**ETA** an alternate matcher (see comments)

You can write your own alternate string matcher:

```
proc altmatch {patterns string} {
    foreach pattern $patterns {
        if {[string match $pattern $string]} {
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

If any of the patterns match, you get 1; if none of the patterns match, you get 0.

```
% altmatch {*bar f?o} foobar
1
% altmatch {*bar f?o} fao
1
% altmatch {*bar f?o} foa
0
```

For those who have a modern Tcl version, you can actually add it to the `string` ensemble so it works like other `string` commands. Put it in the right namespace:

```
proc ::tcl::string::altmatch {patterns string} {
    ... as before ...
```

and install it like this:

```
% set map [namespace ensemble configure string -map]
% dict set map altmatch ::tcl::string::altmatch
% namespace ensemble configure string -map $map
```

Documentation:
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works without the double quotes!
Later in the script i also have multiple string patterns inside an if, that do not pass through:

    elseif [string match {*1TS0*  *DR0*} $hostname] {...

When the *TS0* is alone it works, but when i add the *DR0* it doesnt. Shouldnt it work for these 2(or more) patterns separated by space?

Comment: No, `string match` doesn't allow alternate patterns. Either use multiple invocations, or use `regexp` instead.

Comment: @TasosBu: I added a custom command to do such an alternate match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

This command:

```
if {[string match "{*CGN01}" $hostname] || $hostname == "AthMet1BG01"} {
```

is *syntactically* valid but I really don't think that you want to use that pattern with `string match`. I'd guess that you really want:

```
if {[string match "*CGN01" $hostname] || $hostname == "AthMet1BG01"} {
```

The `{`braces`}` inside that pattern are not actually meaningful (`string match` only does a subset of the full capabilities of a glob match) so with your erroneous pattern you're actually trying to match a `{` at the start of `$hostname`, any number of characters, and then `CGN01}` at the end of `$hostname`. ***With the literal braces.*** Simply removing the braces lets `PhiMSC1CGN01` match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked without the double quotes! Later in the script i also have multiple string patterns inside an if, that do not pass through: elseif [string match {1TS0 DR0} $hostname] {... When the TS0 is alone it works, but when i add the DR0 it doesnt. Shouldnt it work for these 2(or more) patterns separated by space?

Comment: `string match` only matches against one pattern. You need to use `… {[string match *1TS0 $hostname] || [string match *DR0 $hostname]} …` to match multiple ones, or use `switch -glob -- $hostname { *DR0 - *1TS0 { ... } }` (which I prefer in these complex cases, where I don't use a regular expression approach instead).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!